# ggplot2 + geom_bar() disappearing bars bug

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have encountered a strange "bug" when I use `purrr::map` to plot a series of stacked bar charts with `ggplot2::facet_grid` and not all the data gets displayed (some of it gets discarded as missing values for some reason), seemingly at random. Each facet in these plots should have bars stacked to 100.

```
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 3.5.1
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 3.5.1
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date

data_bot2 <- structure(list(date = structure(c(1316390400, 1316390400, 1316390400, 
                  1316390400, 1316390400, 1316390400, 1316390400, 1316390400, 1316390400, 
                  1316390400, 1316390400, 1316390400, 1316390400, 1316390400, 1316390400, 
                  1316390400, 1316390400, 1316390400, 1316390400, 1316390400, 1316390400, 
                  1316390400, 1316390400, 1316390400, 1316390400, 1316390400, 1316390400, 
                  1316390400, 1316390400, 1316390400, 1316390400, 1316390400, 1316390400, 
                  1316390400, 1316390400, 1320796800, 1320796800, 1320796800, 1320796800, 
                  1320796800, 1320796800, 1320796800, 1316390400, 1316390400, 1316390400, 
                  1316390400, 1316390400, 1316390400, 1316390400, 1320796800, 1320796800, 
                  1320796800, 1320796800, 1320796800, 1320796800, 1320796800, 1316390400, 
                  1316390400, 1316390400, 1316390400, 1316390400, 1316390400, 1316390400, 
                  1320796800, 1320796800, 1320796800, 1320796800, 1320796800, 1320796800, 
                  1320796800, 1316390400, 1316390400, 1316390400, 1316390400, 1316390400, 
                  1316390400, 1316390400, 1320796800, 1320796800, 1320796800, 1320796800, 
                  1320796800, 1320796800, 1320796800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
                  ), tzone = "UTC"), fraction = c(76.85279188, 0, 2.984771574, 
                  3.736040609, 12.40609137, 0, 4.020304569, 84.01579713, 0, 0, 
                  6.110995635, 3.824568697, 0, 6.048638537, 86.14848032, 0, 1.868460389, 
                  3.836571998, 5.605381166, 0, 2.541106129, 78.49196539, 0, 0, 
                  11.42150803, 4.969097651, 0, 5.117428925, 90.9202454, 0, 0, 2.527607362, 
                  4.883435583, 0, 1.668711656, 56.36016139, 0, 28.62603525, 2.951794436, 
                  6.052240391, 0, 6.009768528, 54.99892957, 0, 40.69792336, 2.389210019, 
                  0.464568615, 0, 1.449368444, 60.97046414, 7.243319269, 10.33755274, 
                  8.509142053, 5.977496484, 0, 6.962025316, 78.43915344, 0, 6.084656085, 
                  0, 4.872134039, 0, 10.60405644, 65.43624161, 0, 26.41685309, 
                  2.125279642, 2.218493661, 0, 3.803131991, 74.36273611, 0, 15.22097928, 
                  3.300935265, 2.461947552, 0, 4.653401797, 47.54063753, 15.6217015, 
                  16.38167617, 12.64513405, 1.688832594, 0, 6.122018155), species = structure(c(1L, 
                  2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
                  5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 
                  6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 
                  1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 
                  3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 
                  4L, 6L, 7L), .Label = c("leaf", "stem", "ann", "og", "wc", "weed", 
                  "dead"), class = "factor"), cultivar = c("Alto", "Alto", "Alto", 
                  "Alto", "Alto", "Alto", "Alto", "Commando", "Commando", "Commando", 
                  "Commando", "Commando", "Commando", "Commando", "Alto", "Alto", 
                  "Alto", "Alto", "Alto", "Alto", "Alto", "Commando", "Commando", 
                  "Commando", "Commando", "Commando", "Commando", "Commando", "Alto", 
                  "Alto", "Alto", "Alto", "Alto", "Alto", "Alto", "Alto", "Alto", 
                  "Alto", "Alto", "Alto", "Alto", "Alto", "Commando", "Commando", 
                  "Commando", "Commando", "Commando", "Commando", "Commando", "Commando", 
                  "Commando", "Commando", "Commando", "Commando", "Commando", "Commando", 
                  "Alto", "Alto", "Alto", "Alto", "Alto", "Alto", "Alto", "Alto", 
                  "Alto", "Alto", "Alto", "Alto", "Alto", "Alto", "Commando", "Commando", 
                  "Commando", "Commando", "Commando", "Commando", "Commando", "Commando", 
                  "Commando", "Commando", "Commando", "Commando", "Commando", "Commando"
                  ), block = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), seed_rate = c("12kg", "12kg", 
                  "12kg", "12kg", "12kg", "12kg", "12kg", "12kg", "12kg", "12kg", 
                  "12kg", "12kg", "12kg", "12kg", "18kg", "18kg", "18kg", "18kg", 
                  "18kg", "18kg", "18kg", "18kg", "18kg", "18kg", "18kg", "18kg", 
                  "18kg", "18kg", "12kg", "12kg", "12kg", "12kg", "12kg", "12kg", 
                  "12kg", "12kg", "12kg", "12kg", "12kg", "12kg", "12kg", "12kg", 
                  "12kg", "12kg", "12kg", "12kg", "12kg", "12kg", "12kg", "12kg", 
                  "12kg", "12kg", "12kg", "12kg", "12kg", "12kg", "18kg", "18kg", 
                  "18kg", "18kg", "18kg", "18kg", "18kg", "18kg", "18kg", "18kg", 
                  "18kg", "18kg", "18kg", "18kg", "18kg", "18kg", "18kg", "18kg", 
                  "18kg", "18kg", "18kg", "18kg", "18kg", "18kg", "18kg", "18kg", 
                  "18kg", "18kg")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
                  -84L))
```

.

```
ybreaks <- seq(0, 100, 20)
xbreaks <- seq(floor_date(min(data_bot2$date), "years"), 
               ceiling_date(max(data_bot2$date), "years"), by="1 year")

data_bot2 %>% # FIXME not all data getting plotted for some reason??? Text coding??
  split(.$block) %>%
  map(~ggplot(.) +
        labs(x='Date', y='Dry weight %', fill='Species',
             title=paste('Botanical composition (cut to 4cm), Block', unique(.$block))) +
        theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, vjust=0.5, hjust=1)) +
        geom_bar(mapping=aes(x=date, y=fraction, fill=species), stat='identity') +
        scale_fill_brewer(palette='Paired') +
        facet_grid(cultivar ~ seed_rate ) +
        scale_x_datetime(breaks=xbreaks, labels=year(xbreaks), limits=c(xbreaks[1], tail(xbreaks, 1))) +
        scale_y_continuous(breaks=ybreaks, limits=c(ybreaks[1], tail(ybreaks, 1)))
  )
#> $`1`
#> Warning: Removed 2 rows containing missing values (geom_bar).
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> $`2`
#> Warning: Removed 5 rows containing missing values (geom_bar).
```

[image]

Created on 2018-07-25 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: If I remove the scale control it plots all the data.

Comment: The scale_y_continuous limits are too  fussy and will drop data slightly over 100. The scale_x_datetime seems to drop data also.

Comment: scale_x_datetime limits seem to drop data when there is only one data point.

Comment: Probably a bug. Maybe file an issue on GitHub? https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues

Comment: The issue seems to be the way bar widths are calculated in scale_x_datetime and then displayed in RStudio. Saving the plot to a pdf file shows the bars, but they are very thin. Presumably because datetime is measured in seconds and the x-axis scale is in years.